# pandas, excel: выделить название столбца по условию

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, python-3.6

Возникла проблема: как реализовать в pandas условие, если в столбце dataframe есть значение, которое не должно там быть, то подсветить название столбца. В столбце должны быть только допустимые значения, это какой-то список значений, в примере это только "2", всё другие нудно подсветить и если такое случилось, нужно подсветить название столбца, в данном случае -"b", если значение пропущено ничего делать не надо. За любую помощь буду признателен. Заранее спасибо)

[image: Пример, что должно получиться в результате]

Comment: Надо редактировать свой вопрос, а не создавать его дубликат. Причем, с грамматическими ошибками.

Comment: @strawdog , спасибо, очень помог)

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: А нет особого желания помогать человеку, который долбит один и тот же вопрос, не удосужившись исправить хотя бы опечатки.

Comment: если не можете помочь, то просто пропустите мой вопрос, не за чем просто так критиковать меня)

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь [Pandas Style](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html).

Пример из документации:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Для того, чтобы подсветить наименования столбца в Excel файле можно воспользоваться решением из [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56940961/5741205).

---

PS я вам настоятельно советую все-таки прочесть [вопрос и ответ о том как следует оформлять вопросы по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/) и приводить в вопросе примеры данных в воспроизводимом виде, а не скриншотом и желаемый результат. В ответе по ссылке я постарался доступно объяснить почему так важно приводить в вопросе примеры дынных **в воспроизводимом виде** и желаемый результат.

Comment: спасибо, но не совсем то что надо, нужно если в столбце dataframe есть значение, которое не должно там быть, то подсветить название столбца.

Comment: @ValerieOputin, в этом ответе показано как подсвечивать ячейки по условию. Переделать условие в функции - тривиальная задача. Если не справитесь - откройте новый вопрос, но с воспроизводимым примером данных

Comment: @ValerieOputin Посмотрел ваш вопрос, на основе этого ответа составил маленький пример как у вас - если не цифры, подсветить красным, и всё получилось. Почему вы считаете, что это _не совсем то что надо_?